# Issue about plotting ellipse in R

Tags: r, plot

I was trying to plot the ellipse but seems the center has some issue with length.. it said the length of the center should be 2, not sure what does that means because I tried the length(center) it's exactly 2..
Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks in advance:)

```
l2<-c(141, 140, 145, 146, 150, 142, 139)
l3<-c(157, 168, 162, 159, 158, 140, 171)
l4<-c(168, 174, 172, 176, 168, 178, 176)
l5<-c(183, 170, 177, 171, 175, 189, 175)
a.mat<-matrix(c(l3-l2,l5-l4), 7, 2)
dbar<-matrix(c(16, 4), 2, 1)

library(ellipse)
n<-7
p<-4
S<-var(a.mat)
plot(ellipse(S,centre=dbar,t=sqrt(((n-1)*p/(n*(n-p)))*qf(0.95,p,n-p))),type="l",xlim=c(-40,60),ylim=c(-40,40), 
     main="95% Confidence Ellipse for \nSuccessive Yearly Length Increases \nYear3-Year2 and Year5-Year4", xlab = "Year3-Year2",
     ylab = "Year5-Year4")
```

The error is shown as :

````
  centre must be a vector of length 2```

Then I tried:
> length(centre)
[1] 2
````

Comment: Using your code, I do not get your error message, but probably it is related to the `dbar<-matrix(c(16, 4), 2, 1)`. Just `dbar=c(16, 4)` works fine.

Comment: @dcarlson it works! Thank you so much :)